# how to validate a specific field in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I need to do some stuff before saving my data in DB.

the problem is that the data changes during the **validation** and **save** process.

here is some code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Customers();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate('special_field')) {
        // do some stuff
        // data changes here 
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

but `$model->validate('special_field')` function does not work

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? any errors? validation fails? if validation fails check your model rules for `specific_field`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this and it worked properly

```php
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    // your stuff
    if ($model->validate('special_field')) {
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        $errors = $model->errors;
        var_dump($errors);
        die();
    }            
}
```